# Shiny dynamic + filtered dataframe/table output with MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

Basically I'm trying to display a dataframe in R by querying it to MySQL.

I have two filters based on which the values of the dataframe/table will differ. The table is reactive based on the filters chosen by the user.

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
column(4,radioButtons("Stocks", "Stock Number",
choices = c(1: 2),selected='1')),

column(4,radioButtons("Funds", "Fund Name",
choices = list("W" = 1, "L" = 2),selected='1')),

column(4,checkboxGroupInput("Position", "Market Position", 
choices = c(1:5))),

tableOutput("values")
)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output) 
{    
 tableValues<-reactive({
 df<-dbSendQuery(mydb,paste0("SELECT STOCKS,FUNDS,POSITION,INVESTMENTS FROM 
 SUMMARY WHERE USERNAME='1223' and STOCKS=",input$Stocks," AND 
 FUNDS='",input$Funds,"' 
 AND POSITION=",input$position,";"))
 return(df)
 })

output$values <- renderTable({
tableValues()})

}
```

This is what I have now but this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to display the dataframe/table and  make it reactive based on the filters chosen?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - what's the actual error or what's happening? is this query working in a non-shiny (interactive) environment?

Comment: It flags an error- "cannot coerce class 'structure("MySQLResult", package = "RMySQL")' to a data.frame". Is there any other method to display the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error: `error- "cannot coerce class 'structure("MySQLResult", package = "RMySQL")' to a data.frame"`. That's because you've not `fetch`ed the data.

```
server <- function(input, output) 
{    
 tableValues<-reactive({
 query<-dbSendQuery(mydb,paste0("SELECT STOCKS,FUNDS,POSITION,INVESTMENTS FROM 
 SUMMARY WHERE USERNAME='1223' and STOCKS=",input$Stocks," AND 
 FUNDS='",input$Funds,"' 
 AND POSITION=",input$position,";"))
 df = fetch(query, n = -1)
 return(df)
 })

output$values <- renderTable({
tableValues()})

}
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.2-1/topics/dbSendQuery

Comment: Also this will work when I have multiple input like checkbox right?

Comment: It should ideally, because those are anyways part of your query part.

Comment: checkboxGroupInput returns values like, For example  - [1] "1" "2" "3" if we choose the first three numbers. So had to change it to radioButtons which worked just fine.